Dynamic Limb Control Pathing
I want to write a program that will take a model with limbs and given restraints and (provided the model can do it) will be able to control the model and maximize it's speed.
To put it more plainly, I pass in a bunch of connected shapes with numbers like joint angle constraints, and joint force output maximums, and the algorithm is able to control the model such that it moves as quickly as possible along a given path (the pathfinding is an entirely different question that is intricately tied to this part, (like, the model's specs might allow it to wall climb) but it can be created after the fact).
Unfortunately, I've hit a snag: Where do I begin?
Obviously I should start by defining the model, but I can't even decide how I want to define it. Nested objects seems like the top contender, but I'm not sure.
Beyond that, is it worth simulating full leg movement, or do I just use the model to ascertain the possible range of motion of the tip of each limb and the maximum torque it can apply on each relative axis and use that?
This is definitely the most advanced problem I've tackled to date in gamedev, so any and all help is appreciated, just giving me a spot to start would be amazing. Thank you!
P.S. should I tag this with robot? its not for a physical robot, but the principals are all the same.

This will not be a good answer, but hopefully an almost decent breadcrumb. What you're describing has roots in robotic motion planning, which extends the basic notion of pathfinding to include volumetric concerns and degrees of freedom. A useful term to get familiar with is "configuration space", which offers some reduction of complexity. I recommend using "motion planning" as your search term, and maybe start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning
You're onto a tough problem but it'll be fun. Good luck!

Thanks! I've been setting up bezier surfaces for ground design, so I haven't been completely idle on this problem, but I also haven't gotten very far on the problem itself either. Thank you very much for the breadcrumb!
